# Can Gradle consume maven version ranges in parent pom declarations?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, nexus

I am using Gradle to fetch a jar from a nexus maven repository.

In the location that I specify, there is a pom that refers to a parent, but the problem is inside that pom there is a reference to multiple versions when referring to the parent,
 a version range, which Gradle cannot seem to understand/find.
[5,6)

[Could not parse POM, could not find parent.

I have tried [] and various intervals and plugins within build.gradle, but if Gradle cannot do this then it might be time for me to switch to maven.

Comment: As far as I know Gradle can't handle that...maybe uptodate versions of Gradle can that?

Comment: What about specifying a pom.xml / some maven commands that do the job for Gradle?

Comment: As far as I know, Maven before version 3.5.0 cannot handle version ranges in parent declarations as well.

Comment: @JFMeier It looks like maven 3.2.2 started supporting. [release notes](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.2/release-notes.html)